# инспекция кода : реализация бинарного поиска

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

```
  public int BS(int a){

    int first = 0;
    int last = q.length-1;
    int point = q.length/2;

    if (q.length != 0 && a >= q[0] && a <= q[q.length-1]){

        while (a != q[point]){

            if (q[first]==q[last]){
               return -1;
            } else if (a > q[point]){
               first = point+1;
               point = (first + last)/2;
            } else {
               last = point;
               point = (first + last)/2;
            }

        } return point;

    } else {

        return -1;
    }
```

хотелось бы узнать мнение профессионалов : реализован ли действительно бинарный поиск, есть ли не работающие условия, есть ли простор для маневра в сторону оптимизации не убивая "оригинальность"

Comment: Какой-то он сильно не классический. Тут думать надо. Особенно о том, может ли он зациклиться и могут ли `first` и `last` перевернуться. Наличие сдвига в одной ветви и отсутствие в другой смахивают на костыль. Настрораживает `q[first]==q[last]` а ещё нет смысла размазывать присваивание `point` по трём местам - логично его сделать первым в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш алгоритм как минимум содержит классическую ошибку для большинства реализаций бинарного поиска - сложение левого и правого индексов может превысить `Integer.MAX_VALUE` и дать отрицательное значение.

Но в целом работать будет.

```
public int BS(int a){

int first = 0;
int last = q.length-1;
int point = q.length/2;

if (q.length != 0 && a >= q[0] && a <= q[q.length-1]){

    while (a != q[point]){ 

        if (q[first]==q[last]){
           return -1;
        } else if (a > q[point]){
           first = point+1;
           point = (first + last)/2; // возможно переполнение int
        } else {
           last = point; // !!!
           point = (first + last)/2; // возможно переполнение int
        }

    } return point;

} else {

    return -1;
}
```